# Combine multiple results in a colum

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables called request and request relationship as detail below.

**request**

```
reqId  regNum desc 
12     111    Tomato
13     112    Carrot
14     113    Chilli
15     114    Onion
16     115    Garlic
```

**requestRelationship**

```
reqID   relatedRequestId
12      14 
12      16
13      14
13      15
```

What i would like to display like the following information

```
reqId  regNum desc    relateRequest
12     111    Tomato  113,115
13     112    Carrot  113,114
```

Currently i only have the basic query

```
select r.reqId, r.reqNum, r.desc, relateRequest = STUFF((select Distinct ', ' + regNum from request b where b.reqId = a.reqId FOR XML PATH (' ')), 1, 2, '')
from request r
INNER JOIN requestRelationship t WITH (NOLOCK) on r.reqID = t.reqID
order by r.reqId desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `STUFF` essentially needs to join your `request` table on `relatedrequestid` (whereas your outer query is joining on `reqID`), so your whole select should look something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT R.reqID, R.regNum, R.[desc],
       relateRequest = STUFF(
            (SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CAST(R2.regNum AS VARCHAR(10)) 
            FROM request AS R2 
            JOIN requestRelationship AS RR2 
                ON RR2.relatedrequestid = R2.reqID
            WHERE RR2.ReqID = RR.ReqID -- This joins to your outer query. -- You can also join on R.ReqID, doesn't make a difference.
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM request AS R
JOIN requestRelationship AS RR
    ON RR.reqID = R.reqID;
```

Comment: i just wondering if i can display more than 2 relaterequest or more

Comment: @Supermode, What do you mean by more than 2? This should theoretically display as many distinct regnums as there are in the requestrelationship table for any given reqid, unless I'm misunderstanding what you're asking for.